# Cannot ssh to aws ec2 instance (t2-micro)

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to ssh to my ec2 instance

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@xxx.com -vvv
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Connection to xxx.com closed by remote host.
Connection to xxx.com closed.
```

here is the log:

```
debug1: Trying private key: key.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:xxx
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxx.com ([xx.xx.xx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
   #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to xxx.com closed by remote host.
Connection to xxx.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2240, received 1572 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2975060.5, received 2087854.9
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Could you help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: Assuming the instance hasn't been compromised, it sounds like it might not have enough free memory to spawn a shell.  Have you tried a reboot (from the AWS console)?

Comment: Have you tried SSM? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started.html Since your login is ec2-user, you probably have it installed on your machine already, you just need to configure permissions and install the client.

Comment: Open instance console on UI, check what is showing there, you can reboot is instance don't have resources for that check instance stats. Also check security groups it changed.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong user was used. The correct one for my instance is `ubuntu`. So,

`ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@xxx.com`

allowed me successfully to shh. The list of correct users for different `AMI` types can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html#connection-prereqs-get-info-about-instance

Comment: If you select the instance in the EC2 console and hit "connect" it usually tells you the correct user. Not always, but usually.

Comment: It is really so. It is a pity, but I didn't notice it earlier. Thank you.